# Zero-width space with special characters

Tags: android, textview, line-breaks, zero-width-space

Interesting problem here, wondering if anyone has come across it.

I am building an Android app that has some special characters as text (mainly Japanese characters) and our designers want some soft returns strategically placed, incase the text needs to wrap due to width limitations on smaller devices.

The problem is that since the text is essentially Japanese, there are no spaces between words.

I know we can use `\u200b` as a zero-width space resulting in a string like this:

> abcdef\u200bghijklmnop

appearing like this when there is enough room:

> abcdefghijklmnop

and like this if it needs to wrap:

> abcdef
>   ghijklmnop

The problem is that if instead of standard English characters, we use Japanese characters it doesn't seem to work. We don't get soft line breaks at all. It instead always breaks right where it runs out of space regardless of where we put the `\u200b`

> ヘルプヘルプ\u200bヘルプヘルプ

results in:

> ヘルプヘルプヘルプヘ
>   ルプ

Has anyone dealt with this before or have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a custom font?